# Using preg_replace in foreach loop issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to change specific words in a text.

Just "[img]" bbcode's will echo the gallery codes.

Everthing is ok, but foreach loop returns just the firts image.

Here is my code :

```
if(strpos($news['contenu'], '[img]')) {
// Cherche les occurences
preg_match_all('`\[img](.*)\[/img]`U', $news['contenu'], $resultat, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach($resultat[1] as $nb_image)
{
    $image = file_get_contents('V:/WP/BDC/uploads/'.$nb_image.'');
    $image_codes = base64_encode($image);   
    $debut_image = '<image src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf-8;base64,';      
    $fin_image = '" alt="$1"/>';
    $news = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', $debut_image . $image_codes . $fin_image, $news);

}
}
```

Array return (in separately):

- promo1.png
- promo2.png
- promo4.png
- promo3.png

Why my foreach loop (preg_replace) shows only the first image ?

- promo1.png
- promo1.png
- promo1.png
- promo1.png

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I think you only take 1 result `foreach($resultat[1] as $nb_image)`

Comment: Hello, i'm not sur.  
My array return well the right values :   

`Array
(
    [0] => [img]promo1.png[/img]
    [1] => [img]promo2.png[/img]
    [2] => [img]promo4.png[/img]
    [3] => [img]promo3.png[/img]
)
`  
but the str_replace, replace only the first image for the other array values :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually replacing all the `[img]...[/img]` tags during the first iteration of the loop, so there is nothing to replace when the next iteration starts.

You could utilize the `count` argument for `preg_replace`:

> count
>   If specified, this variable will be filled with the number of replacements done.

So your replace becomes:

`$news = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', $debut_image . $image_codes . $fin_image, $news, 1);`